# Create *mut *mut to a struct

Tags: rust, ffi

I'm trying to call `pthread_join` with a pointer to my struct in order that the C thread can fill in the struct to the memory I point it to. (Yes, I'm aware that this is highly unsafe..)

The function signature of `pthread_join`:

```
pub unsafe extern fn pthread_join(native: pthread_t,
                                  value: *mut *mut c_void)
                                  -> c_int
```

I'm doing this as an exercise of porting C code from a book to Rust. The C code:

```
pthread_t   tid1;
struct foo  *fp;
err = pthread_create(&tid1, NULL, thr_fn1, NULL);
err = pthread_join(tid1, (void *)&fp);
```

I came up with this code:

```
extern crate libc;
use libc::{pthread_t, pthread_join};

struct Foo {}

fn main() {
    let tid1:pthread_t = std::mem::uninitialized();
    let mut fp:Box<Foo> = std::mem::uninitialized();
    let value = &mut fp;
    pthread_join(tid1, &mut value);
}
```

But the error I see is:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/bin/11-threads/f04-bogus-pthread-exit.rs:51:24
   |
51 |     pthread_join(tid1, &mut value);
   |                        ^^^^^^^^^^ expected *-ptr, found mutable reference
   |
   = note: expected type `*mut *mut libc::c_void`
              found type `&mut &mut std::boxed::Box<Foo>`
```

Is it even possible to achieve this just using casts, or do I need to transmute?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will work given its calling out to a C lib .. so I'll leave it as a comment. You can [try letting the compiler infer the types .. but you need to cast the value to a pointer (not a reference)](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=73690b49554593f652e397f29b447a90&version=stable)

Comment: @SimonWhitehead this worked! Care to write that into an answer? Matthieu's answer is probably how it *should* be done (giving the ownership over to C and then take it back) but your answer is a good alternative IMO

Comment: @SimonWhitehead Your answer seems gone :(

Comment: @zack I never wrote it as an answer in the end! The answers here are suitable :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several issues here:

- `Box` is a pointer to a heap-allocated resource, you can extract the pointer itself using [`Box::into_raw(some_box)`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/boxed/struct.Box.html#method.into_raw),
- References are not silently coerced into pointers (even though they have the same representation), you need an explicit cast,
- You need to cast from your concrete type to `c_void`, type inference may be able to do that
- You have a reference to a reference to a pointer, you need a pointer to a pointer; you have one too many levels of indirection.

Let's make it work:

```
// pthread interface, reduced
struct Void;

fn sample(_: *mut *mut Void) {}

// actual code
struct Foo {}

fn main() {
    let mut p = Box::into_raw(Box::new(Foo{})) as *mut Void;
    sample(&mut p as *mut _);
}
```

Note that this is leaking memory (as a result of `into_raw`), normally the memory should be shoved back into a `Box` with `from_raw` for the destructor of `Foo` to be called and the memory to be freed.

Comment: What do you mean with "leaking memory"? And: isn't the `Box::new` immediately dropped after finishing the `into_raw` part and causing a dangling pointer?

Comment: @hansaplast: If this was the case, what would be the point of `into_raw`? Have you read the documentation I linked to? It explains exactly the function behavior.

Comment: I did not see the link. Thanks a lot for the documentation, that answers my question above. I *will* shove it back into a box, but what would happen if I didn't? Isn't the memory freed when main ends and p is dropped?

Comment: @hansaplast: `p` is a raw pointer, and raw pointers don't express ownership (or lack of). Rust doesn't know whether `sample` is now responsible for deleting the memory or not, so it won't do anything. If you don't shove it into a `Box`, it will leak. Note that leaking is safe, and in small quantities is harmless (in really large quantities, you'll have issues, however the D or Clang compilers for example do not release their memory to be faster).

Comment: Applied to @hansaplast's problem, this solution leaks memory regardless, since the pointer returned by `into_raw` is unconditionally **overwritten** by `pthread_join`, so the original `Box` is lost entirely. If you *do* turn the (new) value of `p` back into a (new) `Box`, unless it came from Rust in the first place (which seems unlikely since you're calling out to C to obtain it), it could crash or corrupt the allocator when it's eventually dropped.

Comment: @trentcl: Indeed; for `pthread_join` there is no need to allocate anything before passing the pointer.

Answer (score 5):

The code can't work as written; that is because the C thread doesn't really "fill in the struct" in the memory you point to. It is responsible for allocating its own memory (or receiving it from another thread beforehand) and filling it out. The only thing the C thread "returns" is a single *address*, and this address is picked up by `pthread_join`.

This is why `pthread_join` receives a `void **`, i.e. the pointer to a `void *`. That kind of *output parameter* enables `pthread_join` to store (return) the `void *` pointer provided by the freshly finished thread. The thread can provide the pointer either by passing it to `pthread_exit` or by returning it from the `start_routine` passed to `pthread_create`. In Rust, the raw pointer can be received with code like this:

```
let mut c_result: *mut libc::c_void = ptr::null_mut();
libc::pthread_join(tid1, &mut c_result as *mut _);
// C_RESULT now contains the raw pointer returned by the worker's
// start routine, or passed to pthread_exit()
```

The contents and size of the memory that the returned pointer points to are a matter of contract between the thread being joined and the thread that is joining it. If the worker thread is implemented in C and designed to be invoked by other C code, then an obvious choice is for it to allocate memory for a result structure, fill it out, and provide a pointer to allocated memory. For example:

```
struct ThreadResult { ... };

...
ThreadResult *result = malloc(sizeof(struct ThreadResult));
result->field1 = value1;
...
pthread_exit(result);
```

In that case your Rust code that joins the thread can interpret the result by replicating the C structure and picking up its ownership:

```
// obtain a raw-pointer c_result through pthread_join as 
// shown above:
let mut c_result = ...;
libc::pthread_join(tid1, &mut c_result as *mut _);

#[repr(C)]
struct ThreadResult { ... } // fields copy-pasted from C

unsafe {
    // convert the raw pointer to a Rust reference, so that we may
    // inspect its contents
    let result = &mut *(c_result as *mut ThreadResult);

    // ... inspect result.field1, etc ...

    // free the memory allocated in the thread
    libc::free(c_result);
    // RESULT is no longer usable
}
```

Comment: IMO the memory where the pointer points to needs already be allocated (I have this wrong in my example above, I guess it needs to be `std::mem::zeroed()`). From the man page of `pthread_join`: "On return from a successful pthread_join() call with a non-NULL value_ptr argument, the value passed to pthread_exit() by the terminating thread is stored in the location referenced by value_ptr"

Comment: @hansaplast You only need to allocate the storage for pointer-to-pointer. What memory the pointer you obtain that way will point to is anyone's guess. It is not even required to be a valid address - for example, if the thread is canceled, `result_ptr` will contain `libc::PTHREAD_CANCELED` (on Linux).

Comment: Aha, `libc::PTHREAD_CANCELED` is written into the location where the first pointer points to, so it is no longer a pointer-to-pointer then. But what about the other scenario when the thread passes a value to `pthread_exit`? Isn't that value copied to the location the pointer-to-pointer points to? That at least how I understand the explanation in the man page

Comment: @hansaplast It is true that the "value" is copied - but that "value" is simply the value of the pointer itself, i.e. the address. (More precisely, it's a pointer-sized integer which may or may not contain an actual dereferencable address - it can e.g. also be NULL.) The standard doesn't specify whether this pointer points to heap-allocated data, or to static-allocated data, or whether it points to anything at all (in case it's NULL or an arbitrary integer cast to `void *`). That is entirely a matter of contract between the code that calls `pthread_exit` and the code that calls `pthread_join`.

Comment: I've now noticed that as initially written, the code in the answer had the incorrect type for `result_ptr`, which should be `*mut c_void` and not just `c_void`. I've now corrected it (and tested it to compile), which hopefully eliminated some of the confusion.

Comment: thanks for the edit. And indeed when the thread puts a stack allocated struct into `pthread_exit` it's no longer there when I try to access it over `pthread_join` (it's actually segfaulting). I guess the explanation in the man page is a bit misleading in this case

Comment: @hansaplast A stack-allocated struct can't work because a stack is per-thread, so exiting a thread destroys its stack. The man page is correct, as long as you understand that the "value" being copied is simply the pointer supplied to `pthread_exit`. If you take into account that C has no concept of a copy constructor, and that the library function such as `pthread_exit` doesn't know the size of the structure passed to it, it's clear that a more involved copying of the data is out of the question.

Comment: the rust code no longer compiles:  `error[E0605]: non-primitive cast: `*mut libc::c_void` as `&mut ThreadResult``